# How to know in mongoose which conditions did not match during searching?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

I am running search query using mongoose which will return a single document. But sometimes it returns null but I'm unable to trace back the filter conditions which are not satisfying.

More Explanation: Actually I am testing my application which should return a document at every query attempt. But it sometimes returns no document, so in such specific cases, I would like to know which condition of the filter did fail?

Example:

```
db.collection.findOne({'a':'String4a','b':'String4b'})
```

> if above query did not return the result, it mans either
>   'a':'String4a' did not match or 'b':'String4b' didn't match or may be both did not
>   match. **So I want to know what is that particular condition which did
>   not match**

Comment: Elaborate a bit...

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I guess they want to know that if a query like `{ firstName : 'John', lastName : 'Doe' }` returns no results, there's either no one with a first name _"John"_ or no one with a last name _"Doe"_, or both.

Comment: Let me write this... you fire a query looking for a guy with firstname John and Lastname Doe, obviously there is no data that'll matche the criteria so you get no results. Now you want to check If there is someone with first name john or not in db or with lastname Doe. Now, firstly your initial query would like to match both values therefore obviously there can be user John xyx or xyz Doe in your db ... This seems like some weird use case. Explain the use case because your question is not clear, still.

Comment: I have added more explanation to my question

Comment: You're going to have to query each field separately to find out, it's not data that MongoDB will provide (AFAIK).

Comment: hummm.. I thought there could be a way. No prob though, thanks to all of you for all your atempts to answer

Comment: @PointNetworks have you found a way?